# LINQ, Lambda, confused

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Can anybody explain why I don't see the (my) expected output for the WriteLine?
I can see it when I'm debugging it in VS and refresh the 'result' to see its content in my Local window inside VS.
THX

```
Func<Category, bool> del = (Category cat) => { 
    System.Console.WriteLine(cat.CategoryName);
    return cat.CategoryID > 1; 
};


NorthwindEntities nw = new NorthwindEntities();

var result = nw.Categories.Where<Category>(del);

Console.Read();
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, could you post some expected inputs/outputs and what you're actually getting?

Comment: Where do you expect to see the output? Is this a Console Application?

Answer (score 5):

LINQ structures are lazy-evaluated, which means that your lambda function will not be invoked until items are requested from the enumeration (and even then, not necessarily all at once). This should cause the values to be output to the console:

```
var result = nw.Categories.Where<Category>(del).ToList();
```

Please note the implications here: if you did this, the values would be output to the console *twice*:

```
var result = nw.Categories.Where<Category>(del);
var otherVariable = result.ToList();
foreach(var item in result)
{
   // do something
}
```

This is a good reason why you should avoid involving code with side-effects in your LINQ queries.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something with `results` in order for your lambda to exeucute. Try this:

```
var result = nw.Categories.Where<Category>(del);
foreach(var r in result)
{
}
```

As you enumerate over `result` your lambda will be called.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to materialize the query. You `result` is an `IEnumerable`, so the delegate will file only when the `result` is actually enumerated.

Try this: `var result = nw.Categories.Where<Category>(del).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

This is due to `lazy evaluation`. The function hasn't actually been executed yet, so it isn't enumerated until you either enumerate it yourself or you do something like this:

```
Category[] categories = nw.Categories.Where<Category>(del).ToArray();
```

Calling this will invoke the evaluation. You can read up about this on the web but [here](http://www.softwire.com/blog/2012/08/13/dont-be-too-lazy-linqs-lazy-evaluation-gotchas/) is an article to kick things off.